# Howto: Set up knitr (*.Rnw compilation) from in TexStudio

Tags: texstudio, r, knitr

How do I set up TeXstudio to compile xxx.Rnw files?

I am using the TeX-Editor TeXstudio 2.7, on Windows 7, and R 3.01 64-bit.

I would like to write a xxx.Rnw-file in TeXstudio and then from TeXstudio automatically (a) call R, (b) compile the Rnw to tex using knitr, (c) compile the pdf, (d) view the Pdf.

I found these pieces of information regarding the issue

- http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/editors/
- http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/feature-requests/250/

Using the configuration "Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('"test"Rnw')" for the user-defined compilatin command in TeXstudio, I get the error message that the *command could not be started* if I try to compile a sample file.

I would be glad if somebody made this work and is willing to share the configuration of the TeXstudio commands. Thanks a lot in advance!
Jana

Comment: +1, for the Q, I would be glad if you could share your experience writing a .Rnw file from within TexStudio instead of other editors like RStudio IDE. I guess you wanted to do everything in one place, which I prefer also, but after 1 week from your question, did you feel it is now better? if yes, I would like to do the same, if no, please why.

Comment: I will share my very subjective experience(s):
[Positive]: From within TeXstudio all works perfectly fine. All I have used it for (code, ggplot-graphics) worked well.
[Negative] TeXstudio does not (yet?) support syntax highlighting for R-code; further I use the .Rnw to write and archive my scientific papers and most my co-authors do not do sweave which makes it hard for them; also most journals in my field require word-documents. I have to consider if it is worth the effort to export the .Rnw to word for this purpse.

Answer (score 17):

I have solved it.

The command I use in the user-defined commands for compiling and displaying a Rnw-file in my own pdf-viewer is :

```
"C:/whateverYourPathToRonYourMachineIs/R-3.0.1/bin/Rscript.exe" -e "library(knitr); knit2pdf('%.Rnw')" | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex | "C:/whateverYourPathToYourPDFViewerOnYourMachineIs/Foxit Reader.exe" "?am.pdf"
```

[image: Screenshot of the TeXstudio configuration]

Comment: yes,it works well. the command `C:/whateverYourPathToYourPDFViewerOnYourMachineIs/Foxit Reader.exe" "?am.pdf"` can be instead with ` "txs:///view-pdf" "?am.pdf"`, the pdf will be veiwed inside TeXStudio

Comment: How do you embed/mix this rnw code with other code on a tex file with TexStudio?

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  When it finds a " \Sexpr" it says "missing $ inserted. opts_   ,  and some undefined control sequence errors.  And it doesn't accept comments with "#".  How can I solve it?

Comment: OK, I got it.  The file needs to have the Rnw extension.  Anyway I can't get a preview.

Comment: its hard to reproduce the error from my side. The above applies to Windowws 7, and the use of a user-defined pdf viewer...

Comment: Great solution. I've slightly modified it by creating a separate user command for 'user0:knit' (the knit command via Rscript) and then another commant for knit and compile: txs:///user0 | txs:///quick. Same result, but more concise.

Answer (score 7):

Posting this is an answer which is similar to above because this will work for mac and (probably) on other linux based systems.

I use **OS X El Capitan** (mac), and the approach is kind of same. After installing "**knitr**" package, the user command can be defined as

```
R -e "knitr::knit2pdf('%.Rnw')" | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view-pdf-internal
```

This works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

I use the User Commands `knit:knit` with `Rscript.exe -e "library(knitr); knit('%.Rnw')"` and `knit2pdf:knit2pdf` with `txs:///knit | txs:///pdflatex`. This works nice with the magic comment `% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///knit2pdf`