# Using LaTeX as calculator

Tags: calculations, fp

I know that exist several packages, like `fp` that allow to make all kinds of computations.

But I do not understand the correct way to use them.

I need some simple examples of multiplication and division.

I would like compute some data and output them with a custom .sty file.

An Example is:

> Italy = 800 000 km of roads (by wikipedia)
>
> SRS = 14 839.9 km (the paths of the project)
>
> SRSpercent = SRS / Italy * 100

And I would like that `Italy` and `SRS` as the input variables, `SRSpercent` as one of the output variables.

I need this so that I do not have to rewrite the numbers in the papers every day.

Comment: Hint: Though LaTeX can calculate, it is not very fast in doing so.

Comment: This is not a problem for me. I have to compute few data, but these are different in each compilation.

Comment: You might want to specify the question a bit. Right now, it is very very broad.

Comment: Ok. I rewrite the question with more details.

Comment: How many digits after the decimal point should be displayed?

Comment: Two digits. But this is not my problem. I am looking for a simple example for understanding.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a solution that uses LuaLaTeX. No additional floating-point routines need be loaded. The output precision is controlled by the first argument of the `string.format` function; in the example below, the code is set to show 3 digits after the decimal marker.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex   %% needs LuaLaTeX format
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}  % for "\luaexec" macro 
\newcommand\mycalc[1]{%
     \luaexec{ tex.sprint ( string.format( "\%.3f" , #1 ) )}}

\begin{document}
\newcommand{\ItalyRoads}{800000}
\newcommand{\SRSroads}{14839.9}
\newcommand{\SRSpercent}{\mycalc{\SRSroads/\ItalyRoads*100}}

The value of \verb+\SRSpercent+ is \SRSpercent\%.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks. And thanks to all other, the several solutions are interesting.

Answer (score 10):

It's “simple” with `xparse` and `siunitx`. I define

- `\setvariable` with three arguments: the variable name, the value and the unit
- `\printvariable` with one argument and a *-form; the *-form prints just the value with `\num`, whereas the non-starred form prints value and unit with `\SI`
- `\getvalue` that retrieves the value of the variable given as argument to be used in calculations with `\fpeval` that's just a user's level version of `\fp_eval:n`.

Here is a full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx} % also loads xparse and expl3

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\setvariable}{mmm}
 {
  \prop_gclear_new:c { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { value } { #2 }
  \prop_gput:cnn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { unit } { #3 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printvariable}{sm}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \num { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { value } }
   }
   {
    \exp_args:Nnx \SI { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { value } }
        { \__giacomo_get:nn { #2 } { unit } }
   }
 }

% syntactic sugar
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\getvalue}{m}
 {
  \__giacomo_get:nn { #1 } { value }
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__giacomo_get:nn #1 #2
 {
  \prop_item:cn { g_giacomo_var_#1_prop } { #2 }
 }
\cs_set_eq:NN \fpeval \fp_eval:n
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setvariable{Italy}{800000}{\kilo\meter}
\setvariable{SRS}{14839.9}{\kilo\meter}

\begin{document}

According to Wikipedia, Italy has \printvariable{Italy} of roads.
The SRS project refers to \printvariable{SRS}, which is
\fpeval{round(\getvalue{SRS}*100/\getvalue{Italy}, 2)}\%.

\end{document}
```

Operations in `\fpeval` have quite a natural syntax; refer to the `interface3.pdf` manual for the full set.

[image]

### Note

Added `\exp_args:Nnx` in front of `\SI` in the code, because otherwise conflicts may arise when the `siunitx` key `exponent-to-prefix` is set to true (see [Setvariable and siunitx exponent-to-prefix producing error"prefix-only"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273312/setvariable-and-siunitx-exponent-to-prefix-producing-errorprefix-only)).

Answer (score 8):

Here's a `sagetex` approach to implementing a variation on Mico's code. Since it uses Python, it can be easier to see what's going on. But you need Sage installed on your computer or use SagemathCloud if you don't want Sage installed on your computer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sagetex}
\begin{document}
\begin{sagesilent}
SRS = 14839.9
Italy = [800000, "59,433,744"]
output = r"\frac{100(%s)}{%d}"%(str(SRS.n(digits=6)),Italy[0])
\end{sagesilent}
Italy's population is \sagestr{Italy[1]}. The SRS percent is
$\sagestr{output}=\sage{((100*SRS)/Italy[0]).n(digits=4)}\%$.
\end{document}
```

The population of Italy is the second element in the list (represented as a string [s]). The first element is integer data [d] and SRS is floating point [f]. To control the output format, it helps to work with it as a string. You access string data and numerical data via `\sagestr` and `\sage`, respectively. Here is the result running in Sagemath Cloud:
[image]

Sagemath Cloud is [here](https://cloud.sagemath.com/). It's free to open an account.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of pure LaTeX, I suggest mix LaTeX with R code in a "R-noweb" file (plain text file but with  the `.Rnw` extension):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<results='hide'>>=
Italy <- 800000 # km of road by Wikipedia
SRS <- 14839.9 # km the paths of the project
SRSpercent <- SRS / Italy * 100
@
The value of SRSpercent is \Sexpr{round(SRSpercent,2)} \%.
\end{document}
```

Compiled with:

```
Rscript -e "library(knitr); knit('my_sweave_file.Rnw')"
pdflatex my_sweave_file.tex
```

Or just "compile PDF" buttom from Rstudio, the result should be:

> The value of SRSpercent is 1.85 %.

The may be not-so-clear advantages of these approach is that you can (a) use the variables for  much more  that simple arithmetic, (b) any R result (as verbatim text or figures) could be inserted automatically in the  LaTeX document but moreover (c) R can produce some results in LaTeX format (chunks of LaTeX text, tables) and therefore indistinguishable of the LaTeX text.

Just a more complex example to explain what I mean:

[image: MWE2]

```
\documentclass[a5paper,landscape,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document}

<<sourcedata,results="hide",echo=F,message=F>>=
library(Hmisc)
library(xtable)
Italy <- 800000
label(Italy) <-  "km of the Italian road network"
SRS <- 14839.9
label(SRS) <- "km of paved roads by the SRS project"
vkm <- c(Italy,SRS)
km <- data.frame(Italy,SRS) 
rownames(km) <- c("km")
@

\section{Source data}
Statistical data used in this report are only two measures in km of
roads from Italy and the SRS project: 
\begin{itemize}
\item
<<results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
cat(vkm, sep="\n\\item ")
@
\end{itemize}
Is not too much, but it is only a example. Confused with so many data?
See table \ref{xtable}. 
<<showdata,warning=F,results="asis",echo=F,comment="">>=
print(xtable(km, digits=1, 
caption="Data used in this report.",label="xtable"),
booktabs=TRUE,caption.placement="top")
@
\section{Conclusions}
<<percentage,echo=F>>=
SRSpercent <- SRS / Italy * 100
label(SRSpercent) <- "SRS contribution"
@
In the \Sexpr{Italy}~\Sexpr{label(Italy)}, 
the roughly  \Sexpr{options(scipen=6)}\Sexpr{round(SRS,0)} 
\Sexpr{label(SRS)} mean a \Sexpr{label(SRSpercent)} of
\Sexpr{round(SRSpercent,2)}\%. Not enough clear? See figure
\ref{fig:figure} for a better understanding. 
\newpage
<<figure,echo=F,fig.cap="Extension of Italian network road in kilometers",fig.pos="h", fig.height=6>>=
pie(c(Italy-SRS,SRS),labels=c("Others","SRS"), col=c("green","red"))
@
\end{document}
```

And finally, not showed above  (d) R can load data of external files, if you take care of all things that could change in a manuscript when source data has changed, and your replace these by R-generated values/text/tables/figures, you can update entirely a report without touch the LateX template, only compiling again, with the security of zero mistakes in the updates.

Comment: Just for folks who aren't familiar with `R`, you may want to mention how this program should be "compiled".

Comment: @Mico, Yes, I was just searching this on another of my answers to copy&paste.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170625/69174 Here are an answer, @Mico.