# Writing R code in TeXstudio

Tags: r

I have one chapter of my document which include R code. Whole document is written in TeXstudio. I need help regarding writing and executing R code using Texstudio. Regards

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170614/howto-set-up-knitr-rnw-compilation-from-in-texstudio) helpful.

Comment: Could you please specify your problem? Maybe a question? What do you want to achieve? What problems do you face?

Comment: You should really explain a little more about the context you're using this in. Just copying [your post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35136523/914686) from [so] doesn't provide that.