# How do I include R generated plots in LaTex?

Tags: plot, r

I use R for data analysis and to create quite complex graphs. Now I am looking for a nice (and easy) way to include my plots in LaTex. Preferably, vector-based and automatically with the font I am using in LaTeX.

I am using TeXstudio with MiKTeX on Windows 10.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: A decade ago I found out that you can export R plots to PDF. Typically, I crop the results with `pdfcrop` and then include them as any other PDF. This might not be the most modern way, but it works well.

Comment: Does [https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890215](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1890215/7032505) help?

Comment: Not entirely, if I save a pdf then it doesn't automatically take on my LaTeX font. I have tried saving it as an svg which solves the font issue but messes up the alignment...

Comment: The `tikzdevice` library works well. Then you can use `\includegraphics` or if you're using `knitr` you can generate the graph and insert it automatically. See [How to get LaTeX math into Legend of R plot](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/436944) and [Export plots from R directly to Latex](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/510819). Either one of these may be a a near duplicate of your question.

Comment: Take a look at this : [Howto: Set up knitr (*.Rnw compilation) from in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170614/howto-set-up-knitr-rnw-compilation-from-in-texstudio)

Comment: Indeed, `knitr` using the tikz device. [A simple example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/511354/11604)